# R - Expand dataframe to create panel data

Tags: r, panel, expand

I have a dataset where I observe individuals for different years (e.g., individual 1 is observed in 2012 and 2014, while individuals 2 and 3 are only observed in 2016). I would like to expand the data for each individual (i.e., each individual would have 3 rows: 2012, 2014 and 2016) in order to create a panel data with an indicator for whether an individual is observed or not.

My initial dataset is:

| year | individual_id | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 1 | 11 |
| 2014 | 1 | 16 |
| 2016 | 2 | 76 |
| 2016 | 3 | 125 |

And I would like to get something like that:

| year | individual_id | rank | present |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 2014 | 1 | 16 | 1 |
| 2016 | 1 | . | 0 |
| 2012 | 2 | . | 0 |
| 2014 | 2 | . | 0 |
| 2016 | 2 | 76 | 1 |
| 2012 | 3 | . | 0 |
| 2014 | 3 | . | 0 |
| 2016 | 3 | 125 | 1 |

So far I have tried to play with "expand":

```
bys researcher: egen count=count(year)
replace count=3-count+1
bys researcher: replace count=. if _n>1
expand count
```

which gives me 3 rows per individual. Unfortunately this copies one of the initial row, but I am unable to go from there to the final desired dataset.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand.grid` to create a data frame of all combinations your inputs. Then full join the tables together and add a condition to determine if the individual was present that year or not.

```
library(dplyr)

dt = data.frame(
  year = c(2012,2014,2016,2016),
  individual_id = c(1,1,2,3),
  rank = c(11,16,76,125)
)

exp = expand.grid(year = c(2012,2014,2016), individual_id = c(1:3))

dt %>%
  full_join(exp, by = c("year","individual_id")) %>%
  mutate(present = ifelse(!is.na(rank), 1, 0)) %>%
  arrange(individual_id, year)
```

```
  year individual_id rank present
1 2012             1   11       1
2 2014             1   16       1
3 2016             1   NA       0
4 2012             2   NA       0
5 2014             2   NA       0
6 2016             2   76       1
7 2012             3   NA       0
8 2014             3   NA       0
9 2016             3  125       1
```